# Is it possible for git lfs pull to ignore some files / folders?

Tags: git, git-lfs

Short question: 
Is it possible to configure git such that regular git pull will ignore some files?

Problem description:
I have a repository that includes some large data files (stored using git lfs)

While some developers who work on the data files need updated versions of these files, other developers need the files, but not necessarily the most recent version.

They do need updated code versions. And the data files are in the same repository as the code.

I want to set up for way that a regular pull wouldn't update the data files.

- I know it's possible to do a pull without downloading files from LFS, but this will replace the files with pointer files, and I need the previous version of the files.

Answer (score 21):

I ran into [this man page](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-fetch.1.ronn), I didn't tested but hopefully it helps:

---

### INCLUDE AND EXCLUDE

You can configure Git LFS to only fetch objects to satisfy references in certain
paths of the repo, and/or to exclude certain paths of the repo, to reduce the
time you spend downloading things you do not use.

In gitconfig, set lfs.fetchinclude and lfs.fetchexclude to comma-separated lists
of paths to include/exclude in the fetch (wildcard matching as per gitignore).
Only paths which are matched by fetchinclude and not matched by fetchexclude
will have objects fetched for them.

#### Examples:

- `git config lfs.fetchinclude "textures,images/foo*"`

  This will only fetch objects referenced in paths in the textures folder, and
  files called foo* in the images folder
- `git config lfs.fetchinclude "*.jpg,*.png,*.tga"`

  Only fetch JPG/PNG/TGA files, wherever they are in the repository
- `git config lfs.fetchexclude "media/reallybigfiles"`

  Don't fetch any LFS objects referenced in the folder media/reallybigfiles, but
  fetch everything else
- `git config lfs.fetchinclude "media"`
  `git config lfs.fetchexclude "media/excessive"`

  Only fetch LFS objects in the 'media' folder, but exclude those in one of its
  subfolders.

Comment: Note: if you're cloning a repository afresh, you can use `git lfs clone repo.git --include="includes" --exclude="excludes"`

Comment: This answer seems out of date. I get: "WARNING: 'git lfs clone' is deprecated and will not be updated with new flags from 'git clone'" - is there a way to exclude with normal `git clone` ?

Comment: You can do it like this: `git clone --config lfs.fetchinclude='/path/to/includes/**/*' repo.git`

Comment: Note that for `fetchinclude` and `fetchexclude`, they are now preferred to be in the `.lfsconfig` file by using `git config -f .lfsconfig lfs.fetchexclude  "your_filters"`

Answer (score 5):

if you want to **ignore all** git lfs files:

```
export GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1
```

before you clone/pull

Answer (score 0):

### ***`git checkout patch (choose files to checkout)`***

The only way i can think of to do something like this is to use partial checkout

```
git checkout -p
```

It will allow you to choose which files will be checked out manually.

[image]

Comment: doesn't work.
doesn't this flag means ignore local changes (and not remote changes)?